# How to deserialize a Json string that has an array of objects but is not using square brackets

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm trying to deserialize a Json string that has an array with no containing brackets.

```
{ "id": "983f90j30909j3f",
  "moreInfo": {
      "info193802": { ... },
      "info920938": { ... },
      "info849028": { ... }
  }
}
```

This "moreInfo" is an array of items with dynamic keys and does not have square brackets telling that it's an array.

I've tried to deserialize it with Newtonsoft.Json normally ( `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<rootObject>()` ) but since this json array isn't really an array it throws an error. Here is my class:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public MoreInfo MoreInfo { get; set; }
}


public class MoreInfo
{   
    public List<Info> InfoList{ get; set; }
}

public class Info
{
    properties...
}
```

How do I go about deserializing this?

Comment: use `IDictionary<string, Info> MoreInfo { get; set; }` for the multiple keys.

Comment: You're misunderstanding something important: `moreInfo` is _not_ an array. It is an object, just like the root object. Thinking it is an array is where you're getting in trouble. Because it's an object and not an array, you need to represent it as a dictionary instead of a list, as explained in some of the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the root object to use `IDictionary<string, Info>`

```
public class RootObject {
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<string, Info> MoreInfo { get; set; }
}
```

the dynamic keys will be the key in the dictionary.

Once parsed you access the info via the dictionary's keys

```
Info info = rootObject.MoreInfo["info193802"];
```

Comment: Clever approach, completely overlooked that solution.

Answer (score 0):

Newtonsoft can correctly parse the data.  The data represents objects, they happen to be nested fairly deep.  You can accomplish it a couple of ways, for instance:

```
dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response);
var info = json["moreinfo:info913802:example"].Value;
```

Your other option would be to use Visual Studio, let it create an object you can deserialize to.

1. Edit
2. Paste Special
3. As JSON

Output would be:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public Moreinfo moreInfo { get; set; }
}

public class Moreinfo
{
    public Info193802 info193802 { get; set; }
    public Info920938 info920938 { get; set; }
    public Info849028 info849028 { get; set; }
}

public class Info193802
{
    public string Example { get; set; }
}

public class Info920938
{
    public string Example { get; set; }
}

public class Info849028
{
    public string Example { get; set; }
}
```

The source JSON I used was yours, with one exception:

```
{ "id": "983f90j30909j3f",
  "moreInfo": {
      "info193802": { "Example" : "Blah" },
      "info920938": { "Example" : "Blah" },
      "info849028": {"Example" : "Blah" }
  }
}
```

Comment: That generated code would work for the exact JSON that is listed in the question, but doesn't it stand to reason that it was just an example, and a real dataset may not use those three specific `infoNNNNNN` property names but may have any other similar names, and more or fewer of them? I don't think hard coding classes with these property names will work in the long run.

Comment: @MichaelGeary That is possible, but why would the JSON be returned so irregular and inconsistent?  If you're consuming an API it should be consistent, I think the OP needs to provide more information.

Comment: The 'info93739' keys are just placeholders, but they do change everytime, and have varying numbers of them in each 'moreInfo'

Comment: Those `infoNNNNNN` keys look very regular and consistent to me, and I could imagine a structure just like this in any number of scenarios. Examples would be the list of related questions on the right of this SO page, or an FAQ that has many entries with links at the bottom of each entry to other related topics. In both those cases you would expect random-looking numbers like this, but a different _set_ of numbers for each query.